# I have .mpd file with video and audio data downloaded, how can I play it for offline use?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mpeg-dash

I want to ask that I have downloaded data which contains audio and video data separately like 1.mp4, 2.mp4 etc in both audio and video folders.
[image]

Video/Audio folder content :-
[image]

I also have it's .mpd file. How can I play this video ? or is there any way I can combine both videos and audio files in a single one. Single file for e.g. 1.mp4 video or audio nothing seem to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest FFmpeg command that should get you a working mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i master_480.mpd -c copy master_480.mp4
```